# Aframe dependency "three-bmfont-text" producing checksum error

Tags: aframe

I'm developing an AR app with Aframe and AR.js. On local everything installs via npm and it works, but when deploying on heroku it's giving a checksum error:

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
remote:        npm ERR! sha512-FDlyR8SyHQ0Ek38qBx5Hg/AwPuBI/1w/QWpMgzw19Vn81xsDNFTOXJpU0HcvI78C72wwXjJ3T7+EX7k2geDV4Q== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-FDlyR8SyHQ0Ek38qBx5Hg/AwPuBI/1w/QWpMgzw19Vn81xsDNFTOXJpU0HcvI78C72wwXjJ3T7+EX7k2geDV4Q== but got sha512-meJL4/Kwmw321gcX3QwkgeUZ/OM++KyWG+WfuVNCa0HGU8pQdxK2aDS2r8f969xKxjC1kAlMRCqMo4WZ2CebXQ==. (7553 bytes)
```

Searching the sha512 hash pinpoints the "three-bmfont-text" as the package in question. Using node 16.14.0, npm 8.3.1 on both local and heroku. Tried clearing npm cache, deleting node_modules folder and regenerating package-lock.json, but nothing is working.